# Digit increment in Array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to increment (+1) the last digit of an int array that has N values and represents a whole number. Each value is a single digit between 0-9.

The logic is like this: if the digit that has to be incremented is 9, it has to become 0 and the next one (from right to left) has to be incremented by 1. If you reach the first digit of the array and it is a 9, this will become a 10. Examples:

```
[3,4,5,6] -> [3,4,5,7]  
[3,9,2,9] -> [3,9,3,0]  
[3,4,9,9] -> [3,5,0,0]  
[9,9,9,9] -> [10,0,0,0]
```

I had the same exercise but with only 4 digits, so the logic was simple:

```
int[] incrementArrayDigits(int[] fourDigits) {

    if (fourDigits[3] != 9) {
        fourDigits[3]++;
    } else if (fourDigits[2] != 9) {
        fourDigits[3] = 0;
        fourDigits[2]++;
    } else if (fourDigits[1] != 9) {
        fourDigits[3] = 0;
        fourDigits[2] = 0;
        fourDigits[1]++;
    } else if (fourDigits[0] != 9) {
        fourDigits[3] = 0;
        fourDigits[2] = 0;
        fourDigits[1] = 0;
        fourDigits[0]++;
    }

    if (fourDigits[0] == 9 && fourDigits[1] == 9 && fourDigits[2] == 9 && 
        fourDigits[3] == 9) {
        fourDigits[1] = fourDigits[2] = fourDigits[3] = 0;
        fourDigits[0] = 10;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fourDigits));
    return fourDigits;
}
```

I tried to solve the problem for N numbers taking the length of the array and then using a for loop but I cannot reach the expected result.

Comment: Hint: keep an index of the array element you want to increment, starting at `array.length - 1`. In a loop, either increment (and then break) or set to 0 and decrease the index. If the index ends up negative, you've gone through all the permutations...

Comment: Please, show us the loop you have tried to implement.

Comment: Think about how you might do long addition on paper. Start with the right most digit, add, carry the one if needed, then go to the next digit. Keep in mind you might need to add an extra digit at the end for the most significant digit (left most).

Comment: This is an excellent example to explore the wonders of recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use recursion.

The idea is to keep track of which element of the array you are incrementing. You start with the element at index `array.length - 1`, increment it, if it reaches 10, set it to 0, then do the same thing to the element at index `array.length - 2`, and so on.

Also note that since you are changing the array in the method, you don't have to return the array.

```
private static void incrementArrayDigits(int[] array, int position) {
    if (position >= array.length || position < 0) {
        return;
    }
    array[position]++;
    if (array[position] == 10 && position != 0) {
        array[position] = 0;
        incrementArrayDigits(array, position - 1);
    }
}

// usage:

int[] array = {9,9,9};
incrementArrayDigits(array, array.length - 1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, what you really want to achieve is the "PLUS 1". If your N <= 10, use int directly. if your N <=10, use long.

Of course, if you N really need very large. Try implement a class for the digit?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to iterate backwards over your array and increment if needed:

```
private static int[] incrementArrayDigits(int[] fourDigits) {
    for (int i = fourDigits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        fourDigits[i]++; // increment
        if (i > 0) { // cut result to 0-9, if not the first value
            fourDigits[i] %= 10;
        }
        if (fourDigits[i] > 0) { // if no carry is passed break
            break;
        }
    }
    return fourDigits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I came up with. Hope it helps!

```
public void incrementArrayDigits(int[] arr) {
    if(arr == null)
        return;
    int currIndex = arr.length - 1;
    while(currIndex > -1){
        arr[currIndex]++;
        if(arr[currIndex] < 10)
            return;
        else if (currIndex < 1)
            return;
        else
            arr[currIndex--] = 0;
    }
}
```